# ESP32 ADC pins reading non-existent voltage

Tags: microcontroller, adc, esp32

I was working on a project with the ESP32, where I need to read a few voltages and switch LED colors accordingly. My problem is that after flashing my board, the GPIO pins 13, 27, 33, and 34, all read a voltage before I connect anything to them, and still show a voltage after I connect them to ground.

Is there anything I missed in the code or are the pins I used not suitable? Any help is appreciated.

Also sorry that it might not be as readable as it should since there is a bit of german.

Edit 1: The schematic is empty. The ESP is powered by my laptop with nothing connected to the pins. A multimeter reads no voltage between the pins and ground, and as for the readings, they stay around 3700 with no change when connected to ground.

Edit 2: The chip is the ESP32-WROOM-32D

Edit 3: I managed to drop the readings to around 400 by hardcoding the pin numbers in the last for loop.

```c
struct anschluss{
  uint8_t id;
  bool connected;
  uint8_t pinInS;
  uint8_t pinInM;
  uint8_t pinOutM;
  uint8_t trockenPin;
  uint8_t feuchtPin;
};
anschluss erste;
anschluss zweite;
anschluss dritte;
anschluss vierte;
anschluss anschlusse[] = {erste, zweite, dritte, vierte};

uint8_t connections = 0;
uint8_t milliVoltLimit = 150;

void setup() {
  // Set up Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  erste.id = 1;
  erste.connected = false;
  erste.pinInS = 14;
  erste.pinInM = 13;
  erste.pinOutM = 12;
  erste.trockenPin = 2;
  erste.feuchtPin = 0;

  zweite.id = 2;
  zweite.connected = false;
  zweite.pinInS = 25;
  zweite.pinInM = 27;
  zweite.pinOutM = 26;
  zweite.trockenPin = 4;
  zweite.feuchtPin = 16;

  dritte.id = 3;
  dritte.connected = false;
  dritte.pinInS  = 35;
  dritte.pinInM = 33;
  dritte.pinOutM = 32;
  dritte.trockenPin = 17;
  dritte.feuchtPin = 5;
  
  vierte.id = 4;
  vierte.connected = false;
  vierte.pinInS  = 23;
  vierte.pinInM = 34;
  vierte.pinOutM = 22;
  vierte.trockenPin = 18;
  vierte.feuchtPin = 19;

  //Anschluessepins
  //erste
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);

  //zweite
  pinMode(27, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  pinMode(26, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(25, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  digitalWrite(26, HIGH);

  //dritte
  pinMode(33, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  pinMode(32, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(35, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  digitalWrite(32, HIGH);

  //vierte
  pinMode(23, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  pinMode(22, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(34, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  digitalWrite(22, HIGH);

  //LED pins
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(18, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(19, OUTPUT);
}
 
void loop() {
  for (uint8_t n=0; n<4; n++) {
    if (anschlusse[n].connected == false) {
      if (digitalRead(anschlusse[n].pinInS) == HIGH && digitalRead(anschlusse[n].pinInM) == HIGH) {
        anschlusse[n].connected = true;
        digitalWrite(anschlusse[n].pinOutM, LOW);
        digitalWrite(anschlusse[n].trockenPin, HIGH);
        connections++;
      }
    }
  }

  for (uint8_t n=0; n<4; n++) {
    if (analogReadMilliVolts(anschlusse[n].pinInM) > milliVoltLimit) {
      digitalWrite(anschlusse[n].trockenPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(anschlusse[n].feuchtPin, HIGH);
      Serial.println(analogReadMilliVolts(anschlusse[n].pinInM));
    }
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information: What readings do you see. Please show the schematic.

Comment: What voltage do you read with an oscilloscope or multimeter on those pins when the application is running?

Comment: Which ESP32 board are you actually using? What exact type of ESP32 sits on it?